# SQL Finding result in one table based on a second table

Tags: sql

I have two tables and I need to find all invoice that have a ready day of today and have no period in the INumber and all items have not been delivered. Each Invoice may have several rows in Invdetails and I have to find all rows that have a quantity that is not zero.

```
Invoice
Field String: INumber
Field Date: DateReady

InvDetails
Field String: INumber
Field Integer: Quantity
```

Here is my SQL, but it takes long time and sometimes hang I don't know if there is a better way.

```
Select D.* from InvDetails D
Join Invoice I on on D.INumber=I.INumber
where I.Dateready='2019-05-14' and D.Quantity > 0 and I.INumber IS NOT LIKE '%.%'
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Which database?

Comment: I highly suspect the performance problem is from the `I.INumber IS NOT LIKE '%.%'`.

Comment: Do you need all Invoices or all InvDetails?

Comment: Can you describe what the structure of INumber looks like? In other words, can you give some samples of what the data in that field is? I'm very curious about why you have a field named something that would indicate it should be a number, but is instead defined as a string...

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: I tried with out same slow

Comment: Each location have a letter in front of the invoice number. So the INumber looks like this A10000

Comment: Advantage Database Server

Comment: The table have 8 million records. That span over 7 years.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also try scoping the tables down before doing the join, so, you'll be looking at fewer rows...

```
SELECT D.*
FROM (SELECT * FROM Invoice WHERE Dateready = ‘2019-05-14’ AND CHARINDEX(‘.’, INumber) = 0) AS I
LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM InvDetails WHERE Quantity > 0) AS D ON I.INumber = D.INumber
```

Comment: I will give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this query is the correct logic:

```
select D.*
from InvDetails D join
     Invoice I 
     on D.INumber = I.INumber
where I.Dateready = '2019-05-14' and
      D.Quantity > 0 and
      I.INumber IS NOT LIKE '%.%';
```

You want indexes on:

```
create index idx_invoice_dateready_inumber on (dateread, inumber);

create index idx_invoicedetails_inumber_quantity on (inumber, quantity);
```

This should significantly improve the performance of your query.

Comment: Both index exits.

Comment: @KimHJ . . . You have exactly both these indexes, with the columns in these orders?